# Server Event Logs. I need unstructured data of server event logs

Tags: server, event-log, logstash-grok

I need data of server event logs. But whenever I google "*data of server's event logs*", instead of fetching me the data, Google shows me 'approaches' to handle those (server) event logs.

But I need the data of server event logs.
Let me know the sources from where I can have them, other than Windows.
I mean to say like:-

> a. data of event logs of Amazon server,
>   b. data of event logs of
>   google server,
>   c. data of event logs of Apache server,

and so

Comment: Voting to close, as I'm not quite sure what you're asking for... Are you looking for the log formats? Then google for "apache log format example"...

Comment: No , Sir . 
I need the event logs data of various servers. This data should be in unstructured form.